# How to replace pseudo class :placeholder-shown with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form where `<label>` changes on `input:placeholder-shown`(https://jsfiddle.net/Moor/3r1uL9n6/). Works fine, but in only few browsers. How to add and remove some class with jQuery to replace this not-cross-browser `input:placeholder-shown`?

Comment: [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas, but I'm not so experienced with jQuery. How to check if input value zero or not on-the-go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use jQuery:

$("#my_input").on("keydown keypress keyup paste", function () {

    var textColor = $(this).val() ? "red" : "green";

    $("div label").css({"color" : textColor});

});
```

Comment: Tried - It doesn't. Or I'm dumb.

Comment: I'm sure you're not dumb else you couldn't make a JSfiddle! I tried it in your fiddle - when the placeholder attribute is present, but the placeholder is empty or a whitespace, the label is green, but if a non-empty, non-whitespace placeholder is present, the label is red. Isn't this what you were looking for?

Comment: Maybe I made some mistake. Could you please fork my fiddle?

Comment: The point is to change label appearance when user starts input and input is not empty. Placeholder-shown was the only way to define it without javascript or jquery.

Comment: OK, great! Glad I could help